# Catch block does not execute immediately after exception is thrown in try block

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, asynccallback

I have a bit of Javascript code, which is not behaving as I'd expect it to. Can someone tell me what is going on here?

Here's a simplified version:

```
    let recordsProcessed = 0
    await parser(fileBuffer,

      // Process row
      async (row: Record<string, any>) => {
        recordsProcessed += 1
        try {
          console.log('Processing record', recordsProcessed)
          await processRow(row)
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('Failure at record', recordsProcessed)
        }
      }
    ) 

    async parser(fileBuffer: Buffer, rowCb: Function, ...) : Promise<number> {
      ... 
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        parseFile(fileBuffer, options)
          .on('error', (error:any) => reject(error))
          .on('data', async row => await rowCb(row))
          .on('end', (count: any) => resolve(count))
      })
      ...
    }
```

The parser() here is an async function, but it also calls some callbacks passed to it (I'm only showing one here, but there are multiple). It calls the rowCb() callback for each row in a file.

It's the try/catch block within the async callback which is not behaving as I'd expect. I'm using a test file, with three rows, which will cause every call to processRow() to throw an exception. So, I'd expect the output from the console.logs to be:

```
Processing record 1
Failure at record 1
Processing record 2
Failure at record 2
Processing record 3
Failure at record 3
```

But instead I'm getting this:

```
Processing record 1
Processing record 2
Processing record 3
Failure at record 3
Failure at record 3
Failure at record 3
```

Why is this happening? Since I'm awaiting processRow(), shouldn't it be in the same scope as the try/catch block, and therefore the catch() should be processed immediately after the processRow() throws an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's processing multiple lines, `parseFile()` must have some loop inside. It's unclear if it's your code or it's coming from some library, but that loop either expects to work with asynchronous callbacks, or it doesn't. Perhaps those unshown `options` also affect this.

If it used a loop with `await`, the output would be what you expect:

```js
async function thrower(i) {
  throw "throwing " + i;
}

let somevariable = 0;
async function wrapper(i) {
  try {
    somevariable++;
    console.log("calling", i, "(" + somevariable + ")");
    await thrower(i);
  } catch (x) {
    console.log("caught", x, "(" + somevariable + ")");
  }
}

(async function() {
  for await (let i of [1, 2, 3])     // <-- async-aware loop
    wrapper(i);
})()
```

However if it doesn't use `await`, then the loop progresses immediately when `wrapper()` encounters its own `await` line:

```js
async function thrower(i) {
  throw "throwing " + i;
}

let somevariable = 0;
async function wrapper(i) {
  try {
    somevariable++;
    console.log("calling", i, "(" + somevariable + ")");
    await thrower(i);
  } catch (x) {
    console.log("caught", x, "(" + somevariable + ")");
  }
}

(async function() {
  for (let i of [1, 2, 3])           // <-- async-unaware loop
    wrapper(i);
})()
```

And if it's an ancient `forEach()`, then it doesn't matter even if it tries to `await`:

```js
async function thrower(i) {
  throw "throwing " + i;
}

let somevariable = 0;
async function wrapper(i) {
  try {
    somevariable++;
    console.log("calling", i, "(" + somevariable + ")");
    await thrower(i);
  } catch (x) {
    console.log("caught", x, "(" + somevariable + ")");
  }
}

(async function() {
  //[1, 2, 3].forEach(wrapper); // <- would be enough to produce the same output
  [1, 2, 3].forEach(async function(i){
    await wrapper(i);           // <- absolutely futile attempt to wait,
                                //    forEach just can't work asynchronously
  });
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new variable inside of the parser to get the number of the current record. You should use that variable instead of the global one.

```
let recordsProcessed = 0
await parser(fileBuffer,
  // Process row
  async (row: Record<string, any>) => {
    recordsProcessed += 1
    let thisRecordNum = recordsProcessed;
    try {
      console.log('Processing record', thisRecordNum)
      await processRow(row)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Failure at record', thisRecordNum)
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: I was not entirely clear in my question. Your change indeed, does result in the "Failure at record" value to be correct, but I still get three "Processing record" log items, followed by three "Failure at record" items. My real question is, why doesn't each "Failure at record" log occur directly after each "Processing record" log item?

Comment: @user2943799 Oh, that's because the function immediately reruns after the error. The new thread gets to `console.log('Processing...` before the original thread can process the error, go to the catch function, and then finally log `console.log('Failure...`